# FFMPEG UDP output not working

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, udp

I'm currently trying to send a video through ffmpeg to a udp stream. Therefore, I pipe a rawvideo directly into ffmpeg by `ffmpeg.stdin.write(data)`. This are my options/parameters:

```
var ffmpegArgs = [
    '-c:v', 'rawvideo',// input container
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', // input pixel format
    '-s', '600x600', //input size
    '-video_size', '600x600',
    '-i', 'pipe:0', // input source
    '-format', 'mpegts', // output container format
    '-c:v', 'libx264', // output video codec
    '-b:v', '2m', // output bitrate
    'udp://239.255.123.46:1234' // output destination
];
```

What I'm wondering about is: when starting, I immediately get an error saying `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'udp://239.255.123.46:1234'`, but when I put a filename there (to save the video) like `video.mp4`, the video is recorded and rendered all fine and I can open it after stopping.

So why does the UDP streaming not work? Any ideas? When runnning FFMPEG directly from the commandline with a video and then use exactly that UDP stream address, everything is working completely fine.

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `'-format', 'mpegts'` to `'-f', 'mpegts'`. The latter is meant for forcing output (or input) formats.

Comment: Will try it as soon as I can. But why does recording a video then work and streaming to udp then work?

Comment: ffmpeg guesses the format based on extension. A streaming output won't have that.